# managed_file error when uploading multiple files

Tags: database

I am currently using a managed file with `#multiple` set to `TRUE`.

```
    $form[static::FORM_CONTAINER][static::ATTACH_RELEVANT] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#name' => 'attach_relevant[]',
        '#title' => $this->sanitizeString(
            "Attach Relevant Documents"
        ),
        '#default_value' => $this->getFromCache(static::ATTACH_RELEVANT),
        '#attributes' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://forms/complaints/',

        '#multiple' => 'true',
        '#weight' => 5,
    );
```

When I'm using PrivateTempStoreFactory in my form, file uploading throws this error.

> A fatal error occurred: Serialization of \u0027Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile\u0027 is not allowed

When using pretty generic form, that contains only one upload field above, the file upload works fine for the first time. When the *Upload* button is clicked the second time,  it throws this error.

> An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (256 MB) that this server supports.

The mod_security module is missing from Apache.

Any help is appreciated.